# Подгрузка данных по готовности

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Добрый день!
Есть сайт на php (стоит wordpress, но вопрос с ним вряд ли связан).

Я хочу осуществить загрузку данных из удаленного источника, через API и вывести данные на странице. Я реализовал получение данных на php, но проблема в том, что данные приходят частями в интервале от 2с до 2минут. Пробовал сделать проверку на готовность и выдать сразу все данные, но тогда приходится ждать загрузки страницы до тех пор пока не придут все данные.

В php я не силен, и не знаю, как сделать, чтобы загрузка страницы происходила при получении первых данных, а остальные бы догружались динамически, когда страница уже выдана пользователю.

Понимаю, что это скорее всего надо как-то делать через Ajax, но как можно их объединить, чтобы Ajax догружал то, что php не успел догрузить?

И возможно я не знаю, есть ли в Wordpress какие-то инструменты, чтобы работать не с собственной базой данной, а с данными поступающими через api?

Comment: Работать в реальном времени с 3rd party сервером, очень тяжело и не предсказуемо. Я бы советовал кешировать всё и работать через кэш. И обращаться на прямую только когда необходимо. Если по делу то самый простой способ сделать что вы хотите (трансляцию данных) это через websockets.  Тоесть независимые скрипты собирают данные с api серверов и через websocket транслируют их пользователю. websockets можно заменить просто на ajax запросы от пользователя по интервалу.

Comment: JavaScript Ajax запросы вам в помощь.Eсли первые данные получаете быстрее то отобразите страницу с ними а для второй зделайте Ajax запрос после подгрузки страницы (window.onload) . а после получения данных просто обновить нужный участок кода